# Check which image is attached to imageView

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have shown a list of apps installed on device in recyclerView(`Image Attached`), In this, I categorized apps with imageview(`you can see red circle in image`)

I set both icons in coding, based on condition, Now **I want to show toast onclick of item based on imageView i.e. appCategory** , means ...If item have imageView of phone, it shows toast "phone" otherwise "playstore"

> that previous condition, I used to filter is not applicable here as it uses FOR Loop for whole list.

---

**image for reference** - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syvrA.jpg)

*I tried `tag` and following code but doesn't worked for me*

```
if (Category_Apps.drawable.constantState ==
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_phone)!!.constantState) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } 
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Play-store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should save the desired Toast's text in recycle view item itself and you can simply show it on icon click.

```
public class AppListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppListAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<AppItem> appItemList;

    ........
    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        .....
        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //other code for item setup
            icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, appItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getIconText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding !